# Create a stacked graph or bar graph using plotly in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, plotly

I have data like this :

```
[ ('2018-04-09', '10:18:11',['s1',10],['s2',15],['s3',5])

('2018-04-09', '10:20:11',['s4',8],['s2',20],['s1',10])

('2018-04-10', '10:30:11',['s4',10],['s5',6],['s6',3]) ]
```

I want to plot a stacked graph preferably of this data.

X-axis will be time, 
it should be like  this 
[image]

I created this image in paint just to show. 
X axis will show time like normal graph does( 10:00 ,April 3,2018).

I am stuck because the string value (like 's1',or 's2' ) will change in differnt bar graph.

Just to hard code and verify,I try this:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

def createPage():

    graph_data = []

    l1=[('com.p1',1),('com.p2',2)('com.p3',3)]

    l2=[('com.p1',1),('com.p4',2)('com.p5',3)]

    l3=[('com.p2',8),('com.p3',2)('com.p6',30)]

    trace_temp = go.Bar(
                x='2018-04-09 10:18:11',
                y=l1[0],
                name = 'top',
                )

    graph_data.append(trace_temp)


    plotly.offline.plot(graph_data, filename='basic-scatter3.html')

createPage()
```

Error I am getting is `Tuple Object is not callable`.

So can someone please suggest some code for how I can plot such data.
If needed,I may store data in some other form which may be helpful in plotting.

Edit :
I used the approach suggested in accepted answer and succeed in plotting using plotly like this

```
fig=df.iplot(kin='bar',barmode='stack',asFigure=True)

plotly.offline.plt(fig,filename="stack1.html)
```

However I faced one error:

1.When Time intervals are very close,Data overlaps on graph.
Is there a way to overcome it.

Comment: 1) Should the stacked bars be in the same order as in the list? 2) Why do the values (30, 20, 10) from the first list translate in the graph to (10, 15, 5)?

Comment: Order is not necessary.I am sorry for that value error.I make graph on paint so i mis matched the values,will correct them :)

Comment: `('com.p2',2)('com.p3',3)` is actually invalid, maybe you missed a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pandas` stacked bar plot. The advantage is that you can create with `pandas` easily the table of column/value pairs you have to generate anyhow.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

all_data = [('2018-04-09', '10:18:11', ['s1',10],['s2',15],['s3',5]),
            ('2018-04-09', '10:20:11', ['s4',8], ['s2',20],['s1',10]),
            ('2018-04-10', '10:30:11', ['s4',10],['s5',6], ['s6',3]) ]

#load data into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns = list("ABCDE"))
#combine the two descriptors
df["day/time"] = df["A"] + "\n" + df["B"]
#assign each list to a new row with the appropriate day/time label
df = df.melt(id_vars = ["day/time"], value_vars = ["C", "D", "E"])
#split each list into category and value
df[["category", "val"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.value.values.tolist(), index = df.index)
#create a table with category-value pairs from all lists, missing values are set to NaN
df = df.pivot(index = "day/time", columns = "category", values = "val")
#plot a stacked bar chart 
df.plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True)
#give tick labels the right orientation
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
plt.show()
```

Output:
 [image]

Comment: :If I want to view it in the browser after creating xml,wha change i need to do

Comment: T : Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How i link cufflinks with pandas to plot using plotly ?